# How to intergate the cross section over the surface of a detector?

Tags: integration, scattering-cross-section, particle-detectors

My beam moves along the $X$ axis. I know the cross section $\frac{d \sigma}{d \Omega}$. My rectangular detector is perpendicular to the $XY$ plane and its surface is perpendicular to the line connecting the $(0,0,0)$ point and the centre of the detector. The depth of the detector is negligible.

I'd like to calculate the total number of particles an ideal rectangular detector would measure: $$\int_{\phi_1} ^{\phi
_2}   \int_{\theta_1}^{\theta_2} \frac{d \sigma}{d \Omega} \,d \Omega$$

My question is: are the integral limits ($\phi_1$, $\phi
_2$, $\theta_1$, $\theta_2$) independent variables or are they somehow correlated? If so, how can I calculate them?

I can't imagine that really well. I tried drawing an example surface (a section of a sphere) in Mathematica, but I can't tell if it is the right one. The curvature isn't visible (I mean the curvature of the borders of the region, not the curvature of the sphere), but it isn't a proof.

Should I use Monte Carlo methods or Geant instead?

Comment: Am I wrong for thinking that Geant would use Monte Carlo methods as well?

Comment: I'm under the impression that Geant uses Monte Carlo simulation.

Comment: Ok, maybe it does, but there is a difference if I "manually" use Monte Carlo methods or use Geant which will do it for me.

Comment: Differential cross sections seem to be hard to grasp at the beginning. Your integration angles are based on the geometry of you set up. For a small solid angle, the cross section may not change significantly so you could estimate based solely on the solid angle of the detector and the cross section at the center.

Comment: I don't want to estimate the cross section, I want to calculate it.